# Select id from array which is not in table

Tags: mysql

I have a PHP coma separated string of ids like `1,2,3`. I have a MySQL table which has `id` column

Table task_comments:

```
id
--
1
2
```

I want to get all the ids in the list which are not in the table. Here i would like to get the `3` as result.

Currently I am building a query like the following in PHP and it is working.

```
SELECT id FROM (
SELECT 1 id FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 id FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 id FROM DUAL
) a WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM task_comments);
```

I don't think this is a good way to do this. I want to know if there is a better method to do this, because if the list is big the `union` list will grow.

Thanks

PS: I can post the PHP code used to make the query also if needed.
**PPS:** I would like to know if there is better MySQL Query.

Comment: if it is not in table, then how will you get that ?

Comment: @jWeaver, I am building a dynamic notification system. The ids can get added or deleted from other processes and I want to update it. the front end sends the list of ids it currently has. It is too big to reload all the current items every time.

Comment: $array1 = array();
$array2 = array();
$diff = array_diff($array1, $array2);

Comment: @FirmView `array_diff` works, but i would like to know if I can do it with mysql. Need to minimize network traffic as much as possible.

Comment: Do you want to update the number containing table with those numbers that you detected to be not inside the table yet? If not, what is the purpose of the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you do is already the way to do it. There is no other way to create sets to reason over than the (pretty ugly) union construct. You can leave of the "from dual"s and replace the union alls with plain unions to make it shorter - although with a very large list union all might be the more performant solution as it does not sort for duplicate deletion.

```
SELECT id FROM (
SELECT 1 id
UNION
SELECT 2 id
UNION 
SELECT 3 id
) a WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tasklist);
```

You might also want to have a look at temporary tables. That way you could create the set you need in a more natural way without hitting the limits of the large SQL involving unions.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (id int);

INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES((1),(2),(3)); -- or just repeat for as many values as you might have from your app (batch insert?)

SELECT id FROM temp_table
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tasklist);
```

See more on temporary tables [here.](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3844811/Make-Your-MySQL-Queries-More-Efficient-with-Temporary-Tables.htm)

Comment: this seems to be the most appropriate for my situation. I have to live with this till MySQL adds some functionality to select from string.

Answer (score 4):

Your string separated values in PHP:

```
$my_ids = "1,2,3";
```

SQL query in PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM task_comments WHERE id IN ($my_ids)";
```

This will return the id values from database which is 1 or 2 or 3.
Then you can simply compare it.

Comment: much better than selecting all ids

Comment: make sure you have index in `id` field. otherwise it can cause performance issues if table grows bigger

Comment: $query = "SELECT id FROM task_comments WHERE id NOT IN ($my_ids)";

Comment: @FirmView this will return bunch of other ids(if they exist). maybe 4 maybe 10. this is not what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like that: select your ids:

```
SELECT id FROM task_comments WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

(here (1,2,3) is built from your array data - for example, via [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function)

Then, in a cycle, fetch your ids into an array and then use [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to find absent values.

Comment: this will return all ids in task_comments table. what if there are like thousands of records?

Comment: Yes, that could be a problem. Should not select all, only array data enough. Fixed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be you should first save all the distinct `id's` from the table that are present in your string of id's -

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM task_comments WHERE id IN (1,2,3..)
```

and then compare the two.